# How to apply Strikethrough text for broken link(s) in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, navigation

Lets say I've created an article page. which consists several paragraphs (like in Wikipedia). The paragraphs may contains links to external pages.

I would like to validate the external links while page loading. Meaning if the external links are not available/ doesn't exist I need to make the link text strike off.

Let's say in the following example link for  'Website' is not available. So I need to show that link as follows

> Checkout this <strike>[Website](http://d.com)</strike>

I've verified [Link checker](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkchecker) module for this. Using this we can identify broken links  under Reports -> Broken links. (when cron runs)

Is this module helpful to achieve my requirement? Any suggestions?

Comment: "But this didn't meet my requirement." - how so? How have you tried to use it's broken link database to alter link's style? You will always need something to create and maintain database of broken links, to use that database for styling - have link checker failed you in scanning? Link database management? Or you want one tool to do everything?

Comment: @Mołot As of my understand, Link checker module depends on Cron run. If I Run Cron, then  broken links are appearing under Reports -> Broken links.
So I thought that it's not useful. Suggest me if I'm wrong. Any hints?

Comment: So when do you want to scan for broken links? If you want to do it when user requests your page, you will have unacceptable delays, as your server will need to wait for all the other (linked) servers, and then it will need to process their output. Can you afford loading times twice, thrice as slow as the slowest server your users may have a fantasy to link to? I wouldn't risk that. CRON is the only way to have dead link scan without making your readers wait no one knows how long for their pages.

Comment: I believe link checker also shows you the URL status for links on the `Edit Page` of any node. I supposed you could use `hook_url_outbound` for example for any url built by drupal using `l()` or `url()` function -- but that may or not test WYSIWYG urls if they are not include by an input format. As Molot said, validating links while the page is loading -- is a poor idea. A frequent cron job is a better idea. https://www.drupal.org/project/linkchecker_views and the patch in issues to add a relationship to a Node is closer to what you want.

Comment: @Mołot Thanks Molot, Yes I agree. Edited post. I'll try to use this module to achieve my requirement. Thanks again

Comment: @tenken Thanks tenken. Thanks for the hints. I'll try what you have suggested in comment :)